# What is the `/etc/hostname` used/required for?

Tags: boot, sudo, hostname, init

I found in the `/etc/hostname` my IP-address, than I deleted it and each time I use sudo - I get a message and a system email `sudo: unable to resolve host (none)` or if in the `/etc/hostname` is saved `myhostname` than `sudo: unable to resolve host (myhostname)`.

I know it is used to set the system's hostname via `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh` while booting process, but what is this setting required for (programs, services, daemons ...)?

What if i set to `localhost` (so it doesn't happen any `sudo: unable to resolve host (none)` anymore, but is it still ok?)?

**UPD1:**

I found some information here: http://jblevins.org/log/hostname, but it is all about how to use it and not about - why it is required.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0916/ipconfig-13/index.html